# A contradictory consequence of the Tarski-Vaught test in Gödel's constructible universe

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

A consequence of the Tarski-Vaught test is the following: if $(M_i)$ is a chain of elementary end-extension, that is if:
$$
M_0 \prec M_1 \prec \ldots \prec M_i \prec \ldots
$$
Then for all $j$, we have:
$$
M_j \prec \bigcup_i M_i
$$

Then if we consider $L_{\omega_1}$ in the constructible universe, we can construct $(L_{\alpha_\nu})_{\nu}$ a chain of elementary substructures of $L_{\omega_1}$ by repeatedly applying the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem. In particular, this implies that:
$$
L_{\omega_1} \models \exists \alpha \, \forall \beta \, \exists \alpha' > \beta \, L_\alpha \prec L_{\alpha'} 
$$

Now consider $\alpha_0$ the least ordinal such that $L_{\alpha_0} \prec L_{\omega_1}$. The previous sentence can be reflected down to $L_{\alpha_0}$ and this implies the existence of some chain of elementary substructures $(L_{\beta_i})$ such that the $\beta_i$ are cofinal in $\alpha$. Hence, the previous consequence of the Tarski-Vaught test yields:
$$
L_{\beta_0} \prec \bigcup_i L_{\beta_i} = L_{\alpha_0} \prec L_{\omega_1}
$$
which contradict the minimality of $\alpha_0$. Where is the error in this reasonning?

Comment: I think the only error in your argument is the "and this implies" in "The previous sentence can be reflected down to $L_{\alpha_0}$ and this implies the existence of some chain $\dots$." What it actually implies is that there is $\xi<\alpha_0$ such that $L_\xi$ has elementary extensions $L_\eta$ for arbitrarily large $\eta<\alpha_0$. But there is no guarantee that those $L_\eta$'s form an elementary chain. Any two of them, say $L_\eta\subseteq L_{\eta'}$ satisfy the same formulas with parameters from $L_\xi$,  but not necessarily with parameters from $L_\eta$.

Comment: Why did we even need that chain? Why not simply take the least $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha\prec L_{\omega_1}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The chain in $L_{\omega_1}$ or in $L_{\alpha_0}$? The first one is used to establish the sentence in $L_{\omega_1}$, although it could be indeed simply a LS argument. The second one however seems necessary to establish that $L_{\beta_0} \prec L_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That was it indeed! Took it for granted and never tried to write it down.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues. It is true that there are arbitrarily large $\alpha$ below $\omega_1$ such that $L_\alpha\prec L_{\omega_1}$. That's different from saying $L_{\omega_1}\models\exists\alpha\forall\beta\exists\alpha'>\beta\ L_\alpha\prec L_{\alpha'}$, which says a totally different thing; although I feel like $L_{\omega_1}$ *consistently* satisfies this sentence, using something about zero sharp, it's probably not true in general, and moreover $\alpha<\alpha'<\alpha''$, $L_\alpha\prec L_{\alpha'}$ and $L_\alpha\prec L_{\alpha''}$ don't imply $L_{\alpha'}\prec L_{\alpha''}$, so you don't really get a chain.

The main issue is that "there are arbitrarily large $\alpha$ below $\gamma$ such that $L_\alpha\prec L_{\gamma}$" cannot be expressed as a statement $\varphi$ about $L_\gamma$, by your reflection argument; namely, there is no formula $\varphi$ such that $L_\gamma\models\varphi$ iff there are arbitrarily large $\alpha$ below $\gamma$ such that $L_\alpha\prec L_{\gamma}$ (or even "there exists some $\alpha$").

Comment: Oh alright, thanks! As usual the issue lays in what is not written because it seems clear (namely the fact that for $\alpha < \alpha' < \alpha' \ldots$). However, the other direction does hold without much hassle: if some ordinal admits a cofinal chain of e.e.e., then it satisfies the sentence $\exists \alpha \forall \beta \ldots$.